# Time to preview a video in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, video, google-drive-api, preview

I'm using a lot of Google Drive SDK. Now I'm testing with Javascript. Anyway, I'm uploading videos to my account.

When I try to use these videos tells me you need some time to process. Is there some method to calculate the time?, Is that it is for an app and I show it to users.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's an async task that converts the video uploaded to the preview-able format and no time estimation is provided by the API. You can only the files.get resource to see if the files has a `thumbnailLink` or not to see if conversion is completed.